# FriendPickerFragment deprecated/replaced? What should be used?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am using facebook-android-sdk version 4.0.0. Their website says "This class is no longer available in the most recent version of the SDK." I was wondering if they replaced it with a better solution or if they simply removed the feature from their API? How can I let the user go through a list of their friends with the app and select multiple friends?

Comment: I tried to find an alternate, but I couldn't :(

Comment: I also tried to find an alternate. No luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FriendPickerFragment was removed in v4.x of the SDK. We did include the sample code inside the Scrumptious sample app, so you can copy/paste the code from there, and it will work with the new 4.x APIs.

Comment: There are a lot of dependencies missing including the rest of the picker java folder and some xml layout and style resources. Going through and trying to add all the missing ones. I'll let you know if this works after adding all of the missing files! Thanks

Comment: It eventually worked after adding the picker java folder and a lot of resources. Can I ask why the FriendPicker was removed from the Facebook iOS and Android SDKs? I found it very useful and might try to package it and all of its missing dependencies into one gradle package, if you do not mind.